# Закрытие начального окна во время перехода между окнами в javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Возникает ошибка при закрытии текущего окна при переходе между окнами
Код где я хочу закрыть `Main` при открытии `Dish`:

```
public void  dishWindowShow() throws Exception {
    DishWindow dishWindow = new DishWindow();
    dishWindow.showWindow();
    Stage stage = (Stage) MainApplication.getScene().getWindow(); // получаем текущую сцену
    stage.close(); // закрываем текущее окно

}
```

Метод `getScene`:

```
public static Scene getScene() throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MainApplication.class.getResource("main-window.fxml"));
    AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    return scene;
}
```

Проект запускается, но при открытии окна (следовательно и закрытии текущего) вылазят ошибки и начальное окно не закрывается:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml@21-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1858)
    at javafx.fxml@21-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1726)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8935)
    at javafx.controls@21-ea/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
    at javafx.controls@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3980)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1890)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2704)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:183)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:115)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.base@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:270)
    at javafx.fxml@21-ea/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@21-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1855)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.stage.Stage.close()" because "stage" is null
    at com.example.demo/com.example.demo.MainController.dishWindowShow(MainController.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    ... 53 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Пишет то что Stage is null хотя я вроде как передаю туда текущую сцену

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было использовать:

```
((Stage)(((Button)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow())).close();
```

после этого всё работает, ну и `Actionevent event`.